# can meteor and mysql play nicely together?

Tags: mysql, meteor

I have been programming with MySQL as my database. Now, I want to use meteor(JavaScript framework). Can I use MySQL for the database ? Meteor comes with MongoDB by default.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "nice". Attempts have been made (see [this repo](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql)), but I have not tried it myself. Anyway, this is fairly off-topic here and would be better addressed in the Meteor Forums, where alternative database engines are being discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I used Meteor and MySQL in 2 projects and it works greatly (including live query). However, you have to play around some built-in packages to make it works, such as `accounts`, which assume that you always have a `mongodb` connection in the app.

Thus, you have two options:

1. Remove `accounts` package and rewrite your own.
2. Use `mongodb` for `accounts` and MySQL for the other app data.

With the second option, you could only use the `userId` from Meteor and link it to the user data on MySQL. The things is, there are maybe other packages that require `mongodb` to work with, you must have a research about all the packages you need before dealing with `mysql`